# Parse Migration

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I have photo sharing application running on Parse. So if I will migrate to Parse Server, should I change my Android Code or it's just backend thing? And what is the best and the easiest way to migrate from parse without building new system on my own physical server.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are migrating to parse server, you shouldn't need to change your Android code. You will need to update to the latest android sdk and initialize parse with your own serverURL however. The serverURL is wherever you decide to host your parse server.

Hosting parse server is straight forward. Check out the parse server example [here](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example). They have links to one click deployment to a bunch of different paas providers such as heroku. If you have a lot of cloud code the migration process can become more complicated and is probably out of scope for this question. Most of it is outlined in the [docs](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Migrating-an-Existing-Parse-App) however.